# Android 5.0 lollipop - How to capture low resolution bayer raw frame

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I would like to capture low resolution Bayer raw frames from Android 5.0 camera 2 api.(lollipop)
Does anybody know, how to configure request and is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible since:
1. A crop of a raw frame is not well defined
2. Decimation of a raw frame is not well defined.

Since these are the only two options to lower image size, I think you can get small raw images. In practice, I have tried to get lower resolution or cropped raw images in NEXUS 5, and it crashed the application with exception.